# Double QListView using Qt4 Model/View paradigm

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, viewmodel, qlistview

I have a list of lists I have to show to the user. When the user clicks on an element of the first list the second view must update to show the "childs" of the clicked element.

I'm wondering, should I go with `QAbstractListModel` or `QAbstractItemView`? `QAbstractItemView` seems to be much more complex of what I need to do... Can you give me some hints on how to implement what I said at the beginning?

Thank you very much ;), it's my first attempt at implementing a custom model...
Paolo

Answer (score 0):

[QColumnView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcolumnview.html) does what you want.

> QColumnView displays a model in a
>   number of QListViews, one for each
>   hierarchy in the tree. This is
>   sometimes referred to as a cascading
>   list.

You should use tree model with it. There is [example](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/itemviews-simpletreemodel.html).

Comment: Yeah but the way it is implemented, from the user point of view, is not what I would like to get. I just need two QListView.